# I am trying to extract data from previous day in SAS

Tags: sql, ruby, sas, sequel

Is there proc sql code using CURRENT_DATE that I can subtract one day from it in order to extract data from the previous day?

I am trying to automate a report and need the ability to extract data from the previous day.

Comment: Intnx('day',today(),-1)

Comment: When asking we need to see your effort. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
proc sql;
  select * 
    from myTable
   where myDate = intnx("day", today(), -1);
quit;
```

Comment: This returns the following error:  "No authorized routine named "DATE" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.  SQLSTATE=42884

Comment: @Iwc0724:you should add/edit the code (or at least relevant parts) you are executing in your question, the error you mention does not match to this answer, so i guess you are doing something else/different in your code...